# Whats wrong with this weight paint?

Tags: weight-painting

I have an arm and at the inner elbow, its dipping in when bent?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subdivide this certain area, where the bend is happenning, just add a couple of loopcuts

Comment: Are you sure that will fix its

Comment: Its not fixing it

Comment: could you post a screenshot of this part in edit mode of your mesh

Comment: I just did that :)

Comment: Try weight painting over that part as well

Comment: I just added more screenshots of the new weight paint adjustments, still no luck.

Comment: This always seems to be a problem with arms :(

Comment: I think your influence for the upper arm must extend a certain distance PAST the elbow and into the lower arm. Similarly, the influence for the lower arm should extend some distance up into the upper arm. In other words, there needs to be an overlap of weights in that area to get what you want.

Comment: This overlap might need to be done only on the inside surface of the elbow area, the part where the skin of the upper and lower arm touch when the elbow is bent.

Comment: I redid the automatic weights after subdividing it, and now it works :)